# Why does my python function fail to format the datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, parsing, python-3.7

I have read many similar questions, but I cannot figure out why my datetime is failing to parse.  Everything appears to be correct.  I have checked several times for typos.

The line of code:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-02-13T15:36:06.0453079Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z')
```

gives me the error:

```
time data '2020-02-13T15:36:06.0453079Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z'
```

I have imported `datetime`.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong, please?

Comment: ```%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z```, you need zero before ```%f``` to match the expression

Comment: @Babydesta that would match a literal 'Z', but not parse it as a timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apaprently, Python doesn't support parsing the 'Z' identifier for time zones. See e.g. https://discuss.python.org/t/parse-z-timezone-suffix-in-datetime/2220 .

Further, you also have too many decimal digits for your seconds: the `%f` directive parses microseconds, but you go to 1/10 of microseconds (that is, 7 decimals). Remove the last 9, and replace the 'Z' with e.g. 'UTC', and your string will parse:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-02-13T15:36:06.045307UTC', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z')
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 13, 15, 36, 6, 45307)
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work but I can not explain why:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-02-13T15:36:06.0453079Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.0%fZ')
```

Comment: This works because you're matching a literal 'Z'; this doesn't parse the timezone.

Comment: sorry don't know that